# How to run a Python Script in Excel's Power Query

Tags: python, excel, powerquery

I'm looking for a way to execute a python script in Excel's Power Query just like we have in Power Bi. Have you tried this? Is it possible to add that from the advanced editor? I can't find documentation on that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked for the same answer. It seems there is no option to run Python in Excel's Power Query.

As per this list it really only is available in Power BI.

[List of options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/#p)

In the meantime, I am planning to use xlwings to run Python scripts in excel books after I've run Power Query queries. Definitely not ideal.